# How can I get the total of sales for the first month of each salesman

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgresql and I have a table that looks like the one below and I want to know what is the first date of sales for each person and how much the sold that month.

| Name | Date_of_Sale | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 2019-11-13 | $100 |
| Dave | 2019-11-17 | $300 |
| Charlie | 2019-12-04 | $150 |
| Charlie | 2019-12-19 | $100 |
| Dave | 2019-11-11 | $50 |
| Mike | 2019-12-01 | $200 |

So the end result would be:

| Name | First sale | Month | Total Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 2019-11-13 | 2019-11 | $100 |
| Dave | 2019-11-11 | 2019-11 | $350 |
| Charlie | 2019-12-04 | 2019-12 | $250 |

I've used the following code but it doesn't bring back a single month.
Thanks in advance

```
FROM
(
select 
    name,
    to_char(min(date_of_sale), 'YYYY-MM-dd') as first_sale_date,
    concat (LPAD(extract('year' FROM date_of_sale)::text, 4, '0'), '-', LPAD(EXTRACT('month' FROM date_of_sale)::text, 2,'0') ,'-', '01') as month, 
    sum(value) as total_value

from 
    sales



group by 
    name,
    month
) as a
group by 
    name, date_first_sale, total_value´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` and aggregation:

```
select distinct on (name) name, min(date_of_sale), sum(value)
from sales s
group by name, date_trunc('month', date_of_sale)
order by name, min(date_of_sale);
```

You can add `date_trunc('month', date_of_sale)` if you really want.  The query returns the min date, so I don't see why the year/month is needed as well.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a1e8b8df688a8d26f44631bf2c63062) is a db<>fiddle.